# Update Firebase database record automatically #AskFirebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my application, I am creating a user profile record once user authentication is successful. Each user profile can have a list of friends they have invited to the application.

Now for invitations I am using firebase invites. To keep track of friends invitations, I am adding the user record in separate json objects.

Do we have any mechanism in firebase console where a program is triggered for every user profile record creation? So that I can map the newly created user to his friend.(like a trigger, which will be executed for every record insertion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new Firebase feature called Functions allows you to trigger a function when a user is created. Please take a look at [Functions docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) for more info. [Here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users/functions) you can take a look at an example of sending an email to a newly created user which you can modify for your own purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw that Functions Docs. Working on implementation in my app.

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept answer.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to send the people who click on the link to a page in your app that does what you want. So don't put a listener for the invite but on the page that it directs to